# factory girl and timestamp in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I'm trying to put a timestamp in the email to generate uniqueuenss in a users table. I have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    email { "jxt-{ Time.now.to_i.to_s }@jxt.com" }
```

but this is not working with the error:

```
Fri May 03$ rake db:seed --trace
(in /Users/jt/foodie-rails)
rake aborted!
Validation failed: Email is invalid
```

But it seems like this should be working (granted first time I'm using Factory Girl). How would I fix this?

thx

Answer (score 0):

```
 > 3.times{ puts Time.now.to_i.to_s}
 > #=>1367650408
    1367650408
    1367650408
```

You see, the timestamps are same. You need to wait 1s to get unique timestamps.

The emails are duplicate, so they can't be created.

Actually you don't need timestamp. You utilize `sequence` to create unique emails in FactoryGirl directly.

```
sequence(:email) {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
```

Comment: thx, I should have added more info in the question. I'm using FactoryGirl for seeding a unique user in a couple of different places for associated objects so the time issue is not so much of a problem. Sequencing as you point out would actually give us a dupes since the sequence would essentially be restarting. Should prob just override or something but would like to get the timestamp (if only for posterity)

Comment: @timpone, then I guess the reason is email is too long or no hyphen allowed in your validation rule. Besides, if you want to create only one user, that should be fine. If two or more together, timestamp may bring problem.